# List of duplicate values SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Duplicate values can be found using this

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) 
FROM users
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
```

for the data

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL
1    John   asd@example.com
2    Sam    asd@example.com
3    Tom    asd@example.com
4    Bob    bob@example.com
5    mob    bob@example.com
```

But the table I need is

```
NAME             EMAIL
John, Sam, Tom   asd@example.com
Bob, mob         bob@example.com
```

Comment: I need code in mysql

Comment: To count rows use `COUNT(*)` (it is not necessary here to count an expression - email in your case - that must be checked for nulls). To get a string with the names use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, which IIRC works in both MySql and Sqlite, but handles NULL values different between the two (I may be wrong on that last part).

```
SELECT group_concat(name) as Name, email
FROM users
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
```